# storing large number in c

Tags: output, storage

## include

```
  int main(void)
 {
   unsigned long long count=0;
   count=(20000*(200000+1));
   printf("%lu\n",count);            //18446744073414604320
   printf("%llu",count);            //18446744073414604320
   return 0;
 }
```

now for  count=

```
   (2000*(200000+1));            //400002000
```

I dont know whats going on, basically i wanted to **calculate total number of subsets** for a set of size **"n".**

I know :-

```
 total subsets are= (n*(n+1))/2
 constraints      =      1<n<=200000
```

BUT my code fails for extreme value of n.

can anyone plz help me out for giving right output.

thanks!!

Comment: How large is the `unsigned long long` data type on the platform you are using? Possibly there is some integer overflow; what is the output compared the the actual value?

Comment: when i use n=200000

Comment: when i use n=200000, in formula count gives 672747168,but actual answer is 20000100000 .BTW im not using on my pc but on their platform(competetive programming).

Comment: long long has 64 bits , so max value it can store is (2^64 -1 ),which is much greater than final required answer. Im confused and frustates me plzz help me :')

Comment: It sounds like that platform has an annoying non standard 32bit `long long`. Usually those sites require a solution in modular arithmetic, though. BTW, when calculating `count` in your question you are using both 20000 and 20000**0**.

Comment: @Bob__ not at the same time , but yeah for different input test cases.